# HTML table structure is getting flattened

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

Lo here, mighty internets! I'm coding emails (ugh!), so evidently that means more tables than I've written in a decade. Aside from how some deprecated properties get ignored, it seems browsers also flatten the structure of a table.

So, let's say I have [these tables here](http://jsbin.com/pulufojaqa/edit?html,output). The first one outputs as expected, a 2-column layout. The second one doesn't. Adding `tr` and `td` elements to contain the insides of a cell actually breaks the layout.

To see it happen, inspect the resulting output. You'll notice that the second table becomes a bunch of `tr` tags. The `td` that controlled the width:

```
<td width="264" valign="top"></td>
```

is rendered as an empty element, instead of containing its children `tr` and `td` tags.

My question: does anyone know why that's happening?

EDIT: for reference, the W3C validator complains of *stray end tags*, but they're closing something properly. This HTML was auto-generated from a Pug template, I don't think it's invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple mistake - prepare a facepalm.

You forgot to initiate the nested table, aka you forgot to put in a table tag on the interior tables prior to the new TR tag.

The structure needs to be TABLE - TR - TD - TABLE - TR - TD - CONTENT when you use a nested table.

You previously had: TABLE - TR - TD - TR - TD - CONTENT - which results in your code trying to correct itself and move the TRs around into a valid format, creating the weirdness you experieinced.

See below for corrected HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="24" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="264" valign="top">
        <h3>Alles auf einen Blick</h3>
        <p>Zu den Themen EU-Regulierung, Kostenkontrolle, Datenroaming oder Ländergruppen finden Sie wichtige Hinweise auf unseren Info-Seiten.</p>
        <button>Jetzt informieren</button>
      </td>
      <td width="264" valign="top">
        <h3>Schnell zur Lösung</h3>
        <p>Finden Sie jederzeit und unkompliziert den direkten Weg zur Lösung Ihres Anliegens. Unser Hilfe & Service Bereich ist die richtige Anlaufstelle.</p>
        <button>Jetzt entdecken</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>

  <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="24" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="264" valign="top">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Alles auf einen Blick</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Zu den Themen EU-Regulierung, Kostenkontrolle, Datenroaming oder Ländergruppen finden Sie wichtige Hinweise auf unseren Info-Seiten.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button>Jetzt informieren</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
      <td width="264" valign="top">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>Schnell zur Lösung</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Finden Sie jederzeit und unkompliziert den direkten Weg zur Lösung Ihres Anliegens. Unser Hilfe & Service Bereich ist die richtige Anlaufstelle.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button>Jetzt entdecken</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you can't have `tr` inside `td` tags? You need an additional `table` as a container?

Comment: Yeah, it's legit. I added the extra `table` tags and it works. :facepalm: